# Volley with fragments

Tags: android, json, fragment, android-volley

i have used volley to parse json and everything goes well, I've implemented my custom array list adapter to populate the data to the list view, my problem now is that i want it to be on a fragment inside the activity, but i don't know how to do it. here is my code till now, any help well be appreciated.

```
    snapActivity
    import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.VolleyLog;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonObjectRequest;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class snapActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    private String urlJsonObj ="http://www.worldm6no5.com/wp-json/wp/v2/options-snap";
    private String urlJsonObjusr ="http://www.worldm6no5.com/wp-json/wp/v2/snap?per_page=20&page=1";
    private static String TAG = snapActivity.class.getSimpleName();
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;
    private ArrayList<prop> list = new ArrayList<>();
    private customAdap adap;
    private ListView lv;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_snap);
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Please wait...");
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);
        makeJsonObjectRequest();
        adap= new customAdap(this,R.layout.property_layout ,list);
        lv= (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lv);
        lv.setAdapter(adap);

    }
    private void showpDialog() {
        if (!pDialog.isShowing())
            pDialog.show();
    }
    private void hidepDialog() {
        if (pDialog.isShowing())
            pDialog.dismiss();
    }
    private void makeJsonObjectRequest() {
        showpDialog();
        final JsonObjectRequest jsonObjReq = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET,
                urlJsonObj, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                Log.d(TAG, response.toString());
                try {
                    JSONArray snap = response.getJSONArray("arr_0");
                    for (int i = 0; i < snap.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject jo = snap.getJSONObject(i);
                        prop prop = new prop();
                        prop.setTitle(jo.getString("title"));
                        prop.setThumb(jo.getString("thumb"));
                        prop.setDescription(jo.getString("description"));
                        list.add(prop);
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "Error: " + e.getMessage(),
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                adap.notifyDataSetChanged();
                hidepDialog();
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                hidepDialog();
            }
        });
        Controller.getPermission().addToRequestQueue(jsonObjReq);

        final JsonObjectRequest jsonObjRequsr = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET,
                urlJsonObjusr, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                Log.d(TAG, response.toString());
                try {
                    JSONArray snapusr = response.getJSONObject("res").getJSONArray("data");
                    for (int i = 0; i < snapusr.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject jo = snapusr.getJSONObject(i);
                        prop prop = new prop();
                        String x= jo.getJSONObject("title").getString("rendered");
                        prop.setTitle_rendered(x);
                        prop.setOur_content(jo.getString("our_content"));
                        prop.setOur_date(jo.getString("our_date"));
                        prop.setCountry_name(jo.getString("country_name"));
                        prop.setUser_name(jo.getString("user_name"));
                        prop.setUser_sex(jo.getString("user_sex"));
                        list.add(prop);
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "Error: " + e.getMessage(),
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                adap.notifyDataSetChanged();
                hidepDialog();
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                hidepDialog();
            }
        });
        Controller.getPermission().addToRequestQueue(jsonObjRequsr);
    }
}
```

custom adapter class

```
    public class customAdap extends ArrayAdapter<prop> {
    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    private List<prop> list;
    private TextView titren;
    private TextView cont;
    private TextView date;
    private TextView cnm;
    private TextView usrnm;
    private TextView usrsex;
    private TextView desc;
    private TextView title;
    private CircularNetworkImageView thumb;
    private ImageView usrpic;
    private ImageLoader imageLoader;
    private Context context;
    private View convertView;


    public customAdap(Context context,  int resource,  List<prop> list) {
        super(context, R.layout.property_layout, list);
        this.context= context;
        this.list= list;

    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        if (inflater == null)
            inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        if (convertView == null)
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.property_layout, null);

        if (imageLoader == null)
            imageLoader = Controller.getPermission().getImageLoader();

        thumb= (CircularNetworkImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.thumb);
        desc= (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.desc);
        title= (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.tit);
        titren= (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.titren);
        cont= (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.cont);
        date= (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.date);
        cnm= (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.cnm);
        usrnm= (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.usrnm);
        //usrsex= (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.usrsex);
        usrpic= (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.usrpic);

        prop m = list.get(position);

        thumb.setImageUrl(m.getThumb(), imageLoader);
        desc.setText(m.getDescription());
        title.setText(m.getTitle());


        titren.setText(m.getTitle_rendered());
        cont.setText(m.getOur_content());
        date.setText(m.getOur_date());
        cnm.setText(m.getCountry_name());
        usrnm.setText(m.getUser_name());

        // usrsex.setText(m.getUser_sex());
        //using while to check the string against null pinter at first.
      /*  while(usrsex !=null) {
            if (usrsex.getText() == "male") {
                usrpic.setImageResource(R.mipmap.male);
            } else {
                usrpic.setImageResource(R.mipmap.female);
            }
        }*/
        thumb.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Uri uri = Uri.parse("https://www.snapchat.com/"+"add/"+title.getText());
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
                context.startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
        desc.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Uri uri = Uri.parse("https://www.snapchat.com/"+"add/"+title.getText());
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
                context.startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
        return convertView;
    }
}
```

activity_snap xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Relative Layout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context="com.bluen.matno5.snapActivity">




    <List View android:id="@+id/lv"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:dividerHeight="1dp"/>

</Relative Layout>
```

property layout which holds the data

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Linear Layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <Linear Layout   android:id="@+id/main"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <Image View
                        android:id="@+id/logo"
                        android:src="@drawable/logo"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
        </Linear Layout>



        <Linear Layout
                android:layout_below="@+id/one"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_above="@+id/usr"
                android:id="@+id/vip">

                <com.bluen.matno5.CircularNetworkImageView
                        android:id="@+id/thumb"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

                <Text View
                        android:id="@+id/desc"
                        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                        android:background="@drawable/back"
                        android:text="" />

                <Text View android:visibility="gone"
                          android:text=""
                          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                          android:id="@+id/tit"/>


        </Linear Layout>
        <Linear Layout android:layout_width="match_parent"
                      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                      android:layout_below="@+id/vip"
                      android:orientation="horizontal"
                      android:id="@+id/usr">

                <Text View android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                          android:id="@+id/date"
                          android:text=""/>

                <Text View android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                          android:id="@+id/usrnm"
                          android:text=""/>

                <Text View android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                          android:id="@+id/cnm"
                          android:text=""/>

                <com.bluen.matno5.CircularNetworkImageView
                        android:id="@+id/usrpic"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

                <Text View android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                          android:id="@+id/cont"
                          android:text=""/>

                <Text View android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                          android:id="@+id/titren"
                          android:text=""/>

                <Button android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="@string/add"/>

        </`Linear Layout`>
</Linear Layout>
```

Comment: Moving to a fragment changes nothing except that you'll do the same initialization in `onCreateView` instead of `onCreate`

Comment: I need it becouse i want to add other things in the same activity, can you give me instructions on how to do it.

Comment: I meant that it's exactly the same block of code inside `onCreateView`. You add the listview to the fragment xml,  initialize it and the adapter and make the web request